# How can I change the hover opacity effect of a text link when it is clicked?

Tags: jquery, onclick, opacity

How can I unbind the hover opacity effect of a text link when it is clicked?

For instance,

```
a.test {
    text-decoration:none;
}

a.test:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.6 !important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)"; 
    filter:alpha(opacity=60) !important; 
}

<a href="#" class="test">Click Me</a>

$(".test").click(function(){
   $(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
   return false;
})
```

I don't want that opacity hover effect when it is clicked.

Here is the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jqC7w/1/).

**EDIT:**

I would prefer a solution without hack classes. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436629/how-do-i-remove-hover.

Comment: You can't obviously unbind something that has never been binded :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a solution that adds a class which is used to reset the opacity with css.

```
a.test:hover {
    opacity:0.6 !important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=60)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=60) !important;
}

a.test.clicked:hover {
    opacity:1 !important;
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
    filter:alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}


<a href="" class="test">Click Me</a>


$(".test").click(function(){
   return false;
});

$(".test").mousedown(function(){
   $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

$(".test").mouseup(function(){
   $(this).removeClass('clicked');
});
```

Comment: I guess using class hack is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't modify the CSS that creates the `:hover` state, use styles.

```
$('.test').css({'opacity':'1.0 !important','-ms-filter':'',filter:'none !important'});
```

Inline style should be a higher priority than CSS styles.

Comment: this is not going to work since $.css(...) sets the inline style of the element and not the style for when it is hovered.

Comment: Inline style is a higher priority than hover state, so it will override the hover state.