# prevent a :hover

Tags: jquery, css

I am targeting a div using jquery, and in my CSS i have a

```
 div.right-sm:hover{background-color: blue}
```

I want to stop the hover using jquery:

```
$(this).parent('div').removeClass('right-sm:hover');
```

but that doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436629/how-do-i-remove-hover

Answer (score 4):

The part `:hover` is not part of the class. The class is `right-sm`.

You need to remove `right-sm` from the div.

```
$(this).parent('div').removeClass('right-sm');
```

If there is more css in the `right-sm` class, add another class with only the hover settings, and remove that class.

Answer (score 0):

`removeClass` is for removing a *CSS class* from an element (i.e. from its `class` attribute), not for removing an applied style selector.

What you'll need to do instead is override the applied style by applying an inline style to the target.  For example:

```
$(this).parent('div').css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

Or just remove the `right-sm` class.

Answer (score 0):

Given you have a div `<div class="right-sm"></div>` what you would want to do is remove the class. right-sm that is. Code as follows:

`$(this).parent('div').removeClass('right-sm');`

Answer (score 0):

You can't just remove that rule, you'd have to remove the whole `right-sm` class.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make a class style like `.no-hover` and add that with jQuery? It could include:

```
.no-hover:hover
{
    cursor: default;
    color: #000;
}
```

Comment: Also if someone could format this answer for me, it's appreciated (on iPhone at the moment).