# How to remove css : hover using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

css

```
#nextCh:hover{
    margin-right:6px;
}
```

Under some conditions I want to remove this `:hover` event

Something like this:

```
if (indexL == countL) {
    $("#nextCh").css(":hover", "remove");
}
```

Comment: [Check this out.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436629/how-do-i-remove-hover)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
#nextCh.withHover:hover {
   margin-right:6px;
}
```

Then apply the class `withHover` to `#nextCh`.

To remove the hover effect remove the class `withHover`:

```
$("#nextCh").removeClass("withHover");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have the :hover apply to a class which you can remove and add as you wish:

CSS:

```
#nextCh.hover:hover{
    margin-right:6px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
if (indexL == countL) {
    $("#nextCh").removeClass("hover");
}
```